# Repeat Rows per number of elements in next column

Tags: loops, google-sheets, split, flatten, google-query-language

I have the following table:

[image: table 1]

However, I need to convert it into something like this:

[image: table 2]

Meaning that I need to repeat the first Cell times the number of elements in the next cell (assuming we will split them by ";"). I've tried several approaches, but so far nothing came close to the final table I am showing in the picture. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B, ";")), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ))
```

Comment: Yes it did, thanks once again!